# Assign VSTS bug item to next release via Rest API

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfs-workitem, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-devops-rest-api

I have a requirement to assign a VSTS bug item to be fixed in next release using VSTS Rest API. I'm assuming "Microsoft.VSTS.Build.IntegrationBuild" is the field to update with next release version. However this field is not available in VSTS bug item UI([Build and test integration field reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd997786.aspx)). I also need to retrieve the next release information for the project via VSTS API, Is it possible to do this with current VSTS Rest API? Please advice.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There isn't any way to link a bug to a release.

Answer (score 1):

There isn’t the REST API to link bug work item to release. Also, we can’t to do it through UI (e.g. web access)

The work item be linked to the build can be track in the release. So you can link work item to changeset (REST API or manually), then the build associate to this changeset will associate that work item.
[image]